# Why is this bootstrap dropdown not working properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I'm working with the DDR Menu of DotNetNuke. I'm using it on this page: 
http://lumenis.bondtest.nl/Aesthetic

The menu on the bottom is the ddr menu.

[image]

For some reason, the dropdown menu is not getting between the li's, but on top of them.

I'm using this code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default lumenisInnerMenu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lumenisListItems" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                [*>NODE]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

[>NODE]
    <li class="[?SELECTED]dir current[/?][?NODE]HasChildren dropdownmenu [/?]">
    [?ENABLED]
        <a [?!NODE] href="[=URL]" [/?] [?TARGET]target="[=TARGET]"[/?] class="[?NODE]dropdown-toggle[/?]" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#[=ID]">
            <span>[=TEXT]</span>
        </a>
    [?ELSE]
        <a href="#" [?NODE] [/?]> [?NODE]
            <span>[=TEXT]</span>[/?]
        </a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown[=DEPTH]" id="[=ID]">
            [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
    </li>
[/>]
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using two menus? Which one is not working?

Comment: Yea, that's why I said "The menu on the bottom is the ddr menu". The upper one is not responsive. I'm working on the lower one, but wanted to keep the other one till it's all good. So, it's the second menu.

Comment: you must be using wrong links for bootstrap or jquery if you have added it .. can i have a look at your links :)

Comment: your code is fine

Comment: I am using bootstrap v3.3.6
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="bootStrapCSS" runat="server" FilePath="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="8" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="bootstrapJS" runat="server" FilePath="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" ForceProvider="DnnFormBottomProvider" />

Comment: Looks like you already resolved this? Working fine in Chrome